# Grails RestBuilder plugin is not recognized

Tags: eclipse, grails, grails-plugin

Good moorning.
I'm using grails and i need to use RestBuilder, but eclipse does not recognize RestBuilder. I have this things in Build.Config:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0.RC1"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:5.0.0.RC2'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:rest-client-builder:2.1.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:rest:0.8"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-rest-renderers:0.5.1-RC1"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.7"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36"
    runtime "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
```

I tried these imports too:

```
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestResponse
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder
```

Can anyone help me please? I'm using grails 3.1.7. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about this plugin: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder

You can read in readme:

> The code for this plugin has moved to [a subproject of the Grails
>   Data](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/tree/master/grails-datastore-rest-client). Please submit any pull requests there.

Moreover:

> **For Grails 3.x this plugin is no longer necessary and you should**
>   **instead just declare a dependency on the core Grails Data library:**
>
> ```
>  compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:5.0.0.RC2'
> ```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I had another problem with eclipse refresh library system too but i solved without problems. Thank you.

Comment: currently this is the version that works for me using Grails 4.0.0:
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.1.12.RELEASE'